# Specific usage case of prepositions for manner indication

Tags: preposiciones

For the case of manner indication, I am unsure which preposition becomes more appropriate for which instances.

An example of what I mean is :

> Vamos a Italia **en** tren.
>
> Vamos a Italia **a** tren.

Is this second preposition becoming 'en' because this 'a' repetition was deemed for some reason unwarranted?

An example of indication of manner using a may be:

> Lo hice a mano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no", because you could say

> Vamos **a** Italia **a** caballo.
>
> Vamos **a** Italia **a** caballo **a** jugar **a** la comba

It is not an unwanted repetition that makes you change it from `a` to `en`. It's simply that we say "voy *a* caballo" and "voy *en* tren".

Prepositions in every language are tricky, and the intricacies may vary.

It's true that preposition `a` is used to express method (in which way it's done):

> vamos **a** pie

But `en` is used to express the means:

> Vamos **en** tren/barco/coche

Comment: I figured that, and I thank you for your response.

Comment: Summed up, prepositions are very random.  Even between close languages, they can vary widely.

Comment: Think of it as this, "Let's go by train to Italy" vs "Let's go on the train to Italy".

Comment: Y con este +1 llegas a 30 000 puntos. ¡Enhorabuena! Que nunca te falten las ganas para seguir sumando decenas de miles. Los conocimientos te sobran para conseguirlo :)