# Why "a favor" and "en contra" use such particular different prepositions?

Tags: expresiones, preposiciones

The other day I was talking to someone who is learning Spanish, and she said, amid an expression, "en favor o a contra", instead of "a favor o en contra". After correcting her, she asked me why the custom of using "a" and "en" in one way and not the other, and why not using the same in both. I could not reply.

I have had a hard time finding explanations for this. Google has not yield anything satisfactory. Any of you have any idea?

Obviously, "en contra" sound better than "a contra", because we are used to it. However, expressions like "a contracorriente" might indicate that "a contra" is actually reasonable.

Likewise, "a favor" sound better than "en favor", but I see no *a priori* reason why the latter is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: As you said, _en favor_ is correct. However there are some differences in meaning. Read here: https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/a-favor-deen-favor-de/

Comment: As noted by guifa in his comment in [this question about prepositions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23827/5481): "**prepositions are very random**. Even between close languages, they can vary widely."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"En contra" is an [adverbial phrase](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Contra%20y%20en%20contra%20de.htm)

> En contra es una locución adverbial que significa ‘en oposición a’: [...]
>
> Con verbos que significan oponerse a algo o a alguien, se pueden emplear la preposición **contra** o la locución adverbial **en contra de**:

Both `a` and `en` have spatial "usage" as prepositions. Not only "en favor" is valid, but we also say "(ir) a contracorriente", "por contra" (meaning "por el contrario"). I believe that "en contra" is a shortened form of "en [contraposición](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AbeIB77) a".

My guess is that since these particular prepositions explain not only "direction" (Voy **a** Madrid - meaning "hacia", towards) or "situation" (está **a** tu izquierda; está **en** la mesa) but also "mode" (Tú vas **a** pie, yo voy **en** barco) we use 'en' to reflect that we (figuratively rather than physically) **stand** against it (the other idea, suggestion, etc.). Let's compare

- Entró **a** su casa
- Entró **en** su casa

Both carry the same meaning, but (the subtle) connotations could be for the first one more stress in the action ("ir hacia dentro") and for the second the situation or final outcome (llegar físicamente dentro).

Again, for

> Tú vas **a** pie, yo voy **en** barco

I'm *inside* the boat, you move *towards* your destination.

Thus, we can say "a favor" and "en favor": I "flow" with your action or idea for the first one and I "stand" -meaning support. For *contra*, the adverbial phrase "en contra" would be a figuratively position against something. But this might be a far shot.

Answer (score -1):

Prepositions just *are*.  I learned that from English Language & Usage.  You can help your friend learn patterns, to help her remember which preposition to use in certain situations, and you can reassure her that prepositions will probably be her last frontier in her language learning odyssey.  That's about it, though.

Comment: @walen - That was my best effort, and I cited my source.  I look forward to reading better answers.

Comment: you can still explain why they "just are" or when they started "just being". I agree with Walen.

Comment: @BrianH. - Saying that they just *are* means there is no explanation (in my opinion); the question did not ask for etymology.

Comment: Aparente: I agree on your statement that prepositions just _are_. However, as is now, this is more a comment than an answer. Consider editing to include some relevant info or just moving it into comments.